# How to upload PNG/JPEG file using Karate UI Automation for Angular JS applications

Tags: robotframework, ui-automation, karate

We tried with below Robot functionality and also with driver.inputfile method. But we are getting error karate-robot is a dependency or Gradle?

- driver 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload'
- delay(200000)
- robot { app: '^Chrome', highlight: true }
- robot.click('choose-file.png')
- robot.input('/Users/pthomas3/Desktop')
- robot.input(Key.ENTER)
- robot.click('file-name.png')
- robot.input(Key.ENTER)
- delay(1000)
- click('#file-submit')

Comment: if you can't use `driver.inputFiles()` then try via a multi-part API request - else contribute code or look for other solutions please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#file-upload